# How to send secure api requests?

Tags: api, ios, node.js

When a user pays on the iOS app I want to let the node js backend know. What’s a secure way to authenticate the iOS app with the backend? Is it send a secret key and if so how do I keep this safe from

Comment: I think you need to complete your sentence

Comment: Why do you want to authenticate the **app**? Why not authenticate the transaction? I'm concerned that you have phrased it as "pay on the app" and you want the server to "know" instead of using the app to transact on the server. This is sounding like an anti-pattern. And your title and the rest of your post don't work together.

Comment: You can't. Someone could download a copy of the app, change a few things and run it.